# Redux store as an immutable.js map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, immutable.js

I'm getting this error when building my react native app:

> The preloadedState argument passed to createStore has unexpected type
>   of "Object". Expected argument to be an object with the following
>   keys: "height", "width"

I think the redux store should be an [immutable.js Map](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map).

Here is my `createStore` code:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable'
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { Volcalc } from './components/volcalc/Volcalc'
import { width } from './components/width/width.reducer'
import { height } from './components/height/height.reducer'
import React from 'react'

const initialWidth = Map({ 'width1': 20, 'width2': 0, 'width3': 0 })
const initialHeight = Map({ 'height1': 6, 'height2': 0 })
const initialState = Map({height: initialHeight, width: initialWidth})
const reducer = combineReducers({ height, width })
const store = createStore(reducer, initialState)
```

If I change `initialState` to this, it works:

```
const initialState = {height: initialHeight, width: initialWidth}
```

but now the store is not an immuatble.js `map`. How do I make the redux store be an immutable.js `map`? (My reducers do work with an immutable.js map).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using `combineReducers` method comes with default `redux` package, your second argument to the `createStore` always should be a plain JavsScript object.

Since you need to use an immutable object for your initial state in `createStore`, you have to use special implementation of `combineReducers` method which comes with `redux-immutable` package.

You can read the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-immutable) of 'redux-immutable' package to get a better understanding.